# Electron js error - file not found

Tags: debugging, electron

I have a electron app, so in my `dashboard` page i am getting an error look like this

```
Error: Unhandled "error" event.(File not found)
```

I am using `tradingview widget`.

```
var widget = new TradingView.widget({
        // debug: true, // uncomment this line to see Library errors and warnings in the console
        fullscreen: true,
        symbol: 'AA',
        interval: 'D',
        container_id: "tv_chart_container",
        //  BEWARE: no trailing slash is expected in feed URL
        datafeed: new Datafeeds.UDFCompatibleDatafeed("http://abc.loc/api"),
        library_path: "../../assets/charting_library/",
        locale: "en",
        //  Regression Trend-related functionality is not implemented yet, so it's hidden for a while
        drawings_access: { type: 'black', tools: [ { name: "Regression Trend" } ] },
        disabled_features: ["use_localstorage_for_settings"],
        enabled_features: ["study_templates"],
        charts_storage_url: 'http://saveload.tradingview.com',
        charts_storage_api_version: "1.1",
        client_id: 'tradingview.com',
        user_id: 'public_user_id'
    });
```

How can I get the file name which can not be found. Thanks!

Comment: can you provide more detail information

Comment: I am using tradingview widget and in configs have selected path of configs for widget. so I am getting an error when trying to display dashboard page.